# PHP Redis Config - Any time limit issue?

Tags: php, caching, redis, predis, phpredis

I'm new to redis.

I'm using redis in ubuntu with PHP.

My actual process is:

1) read existing records from db table and keep its key in redis db.

2) read data from a file and keep all the keys in redis.

3) compare the keys and do some process (insert / update)

so, once the process is started, cache will be prepared with existing data and start reading from file.

But after 60 seconds exactly, redis stopped working. Redis is till running. Also, php process is not terminated.

I have used redis monitor command. It says "GET my-key" at the end of log.

No error thrown.

Same code is working fine in windows redis. 
As php used TCP to connect redis, Any TCP or Socket config need to be updated? 
Because this error happens only in linux. 
Any config i missed?

Comment: what do you mean "Redis stopped working"? do you mean PHP client or Redis server?

Comment: I mean there is no signal in redis monitor command window.

Comment: can you use `htop` to see is Redis server process running

Comment: I tried with htop but it says htop is not a command

Comment: @LukaSvalina, can you pls check updated question?

Comment: can you post PHP code?  do you create a permanent connection or create new for every read/write to Redis?

Comment: does windows box have the same php.ini configuration, especially `default_socket_timeout`

Comment: In windows `default_socket_timeout` is 60, in Linux it is 60. Changed it to -1 also. But still not working.